# local variable producing different value

Tags: c++, scope

I have called the function like this,

```
decimal2binary(1, 4);
```

By mistake i have re defined the variable `m` in the definition section of the following function

```
void decimal2binary(int m, int n) {
int arr[n];
cout<<"m:"<<m<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
if(m==0)
{
    arr[i]=0;
}
else
{       
    arr[i]=m%2;     
    int m=m/2;
    cout<<"m:"<<m<<endl;
}
}
```

when i ran the code i got the output like this,

```
m:1
m:1184170
m:592085
m:296042
m:148021
```

why this duplicate variable `m` producing the strange value, something like `1184170..592085`. please tell me the reason.

Comment: Is your compiler out of variable names? If no, why would you code like this?

Comment: i am using mingw for c++ compiler

Comment: Thats okay, but I fail to understand the reason behind your else block. Why do you want to name your else block local variable same as your function level variable? Why can't you just rename the variable "m" inside else?

Comment: అభినీట్ గారు , నాకు చాల బాగా అర్ధమయ్యింది.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined another variable with the name `m` in the `else` block, which shadows the function argument `m`, its scope begins right after `int m`, and it's uninitialized in the expression `m/2`.

Comment: why this duplicate variable m producing the raw data

Comment: @BalaYesuChilakalapudi The `m` in `m/2` is already the new variable, not the `m` outside, it's uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

in statement `int m=m/2;` here `m` on right side contains new `m` having garbage value. if you replace line `int m=m/2;` with line `int m;//=m/2;` you will see that value is actually a garbage value of `m` that is `2368340` for 1st case you are dividing this value by 2 to get `1184170(m/2) into m(m)`

Answer (score 1):

You define another variable with same name m inside else block and you performing operation

```
int m =m/2;
```

so compiler this will treat local m not outsider m;
and its give value unpredictable because you not intialize it;

Answer (score 0):

Variable `int m` inside `else` block is not initialised. It contains some garbage value. You are dividing the garbage value by 2. Now when we say, it's uninitialised, it means, it can contain any value within the range of `int`.

I think, what you would like to do instead is::

```
// Inside else block
int temp = m ; // Store the older m value here
int m = temp/2 ;
```

Or the easy way::

```
int temp = m/2 ;
```